# Visual Studio 2010 memory usage during web site project publish

Tags: visual-studio-2010, publish, vs-web-site-project

I've got an Asp.Net web site project that is causing increasingly frustrating memory issues during publish.  Visual Studio operates reasonably well during normal work, and even the build stage is fairly quick (especially after following some of the recommendations in the posts listed below).  However the publish stage is slow, and more to the point causes Visual Studio to consume between 400% and 500% of the memory it consumes on a regular basis (from around 500 Mb to about 2.25 Gb in Task Manager). Furthermore, the increased memory consumption continues for several minutes (5 or 10, in some cases) *after* the Publish Succeeded message appears in Visual Studio.  In fact, that's really the problem - I don't mind not doing much during a publish activity, but once that's done I want to get right back to work, but the memory overload means my whole system is unresponsive for what seems like a looong time after VS seems to be done its work.

The structure of the solution is as follows:

```
Solution
   |
   -Web Site Project
   |
   - Data Access Layer Project
   |
   - Data Access Layer Tests
```

Both the DAL and some of the code behind rely on an external library for ERP system access, but I'm pretty careful about keeping them both on the same version (in fact, I have to be - some pages on the site break if the versions aren't the same). I have a couple of other small helper libraries that I'm also pretty careful about - in both projects they're all referenced from a shared folder. I don't think I'm suffering from "[Dueling Assembly References](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/30/Common-Gotcha_3A00_-Slow-VS-2005-Web-Site-Build-Performance-Because-of-_1C20_Dueling-Assembly-References_1D20_.aspx)"

The web site is set up with the "Allow this precompiled site to be updateable" flag on and the "Use fixed naming and single page assemblies" flag on.

The over all solution started in it's current embodiment as a VS 2005/Asp .Net 2.0 site.  We skipped 2008 and are now running it under VS 2010/Asp .Net 3.5. The problems I'm seeing occurred to a greater or lesser degree under VS2005, and definitely followed me from my old machine (which was somewhat underpowered) to this, seemingly pretty up-to-date, one.

The machine I am building from is a Win7 64-bit machine with 8 Gb memory. I am running a few AddIns/Extensions in VS (notably Telerik's JustMock and DevExpress's CodeRush/RefactorPro).

I have perused several other general memory/performance related threads on SO (including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168375/visual-studio-memory-usage) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations)) and followed the recommendations I believed to be relevant.

Anyone else ever seen this, or have any pointers to what I might be able to do to alleviate it?

***EDIT***

FWIW, I am publishing this to a folder on my local machine, so I don't think the issue has anything to do with network latency...

Answer (score 1):

Circling back around to this now.  I've moved on from this position and don't have the same problem in my new position, but working out a "building solution takes forEVAR" issue in my new position pointed me down the road of making sure that my breakpoints are kept at a reasonable level - I was experiencing very long build times, but after deleting all breakpoints (most of which weren't being used) the build times improved by a factor of ten.

It's very possible I was suffering form the same issue on the project mentioned in this question, so perhaps that'll help someone who's having this problem.